# Sorting ggplot barplot x-axis in descending order (only one variable on the x-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a big dataframe (AKA "all_data") of words that were presented as an Arabic audio to participants who then had to choose from four options what they thought the word meant in English. Their choice is recorded in the choice column, and what the correct answer should have been is in a different one:

[Preview of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a1XS.png)

Anyway, I wanted to kind of add a column to this "all_data" df that shows their most frequent response even if it wasn't the target word, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. So, moving on, I atleast wanted to visualize it so I created barplots so I could individually check each of the 100 words to see what people thought this word sounded like--so I filtered the word in question (doing this for each of the 100 words is tedious I know) and then made the x-axis the "Choice" column as you can see in the code below:

```
ggplot(filter(all_data, Correct == "Stormy"), aes((Choice))) + geom_bar()
```

This leads to the bar plot you see on the bottom right of the print screen I showed.

I tried several things to to rearrange the x-axis in order of frequency but nothing worked! I have searched on all the other threads similar to this question but they all have a y-axis to use in the reordering, which I do not have and therefore I always get errors.

I understand there is technically no defined y-axis so R kind of creates its own 'count' of the words on the x-axis but I can't seem to figure out how to get the name for this count in the y-axis as you can see in my so many attempts above.

Anyway after all that I've just been viewing my plots in the normal way and making notes but is there anything anyone can do to help with any of my problems?

Much appreciated!

Ahsan

Comment: just set the factor levels `all_data$Correct <- factor(all_data$Correct, names(sort(table(all_data$Correct), decreasing = TRUE)))` or similar. there is no need to show every attempt you made, one is sufficient

Comment: As I'm still quite a novice at R that thread kind of went over my head. I have done what @rawr has said but I'm unsure of what code to input after having set the factor levels.

Comment: `ggplot(filter(all_data, Correct == "He came"), aes(Choice)) + geom_bar()`

Comment: I have tried this. Am I missing something here when I input the following code:

`all_data$Correct <- factor(all_data$Correct, names(sort(table(all_data$Correct), decreasing = TRUE)))
ggplot(filter(all_data, Correct == "He came"), aes(Choice)) + geom_bar()`

The same barchart unchanged comes up

Comment: Also @stefan no it did not because they have predetermined x and y axes

Comment: @Md.Ahsan Sorry. Wasn't meant bad. But your are right. Even if I'm sure that there is already an answer on SO, this one was for sure not the easiest to understand and the problem asked there was way more complicated. If you are looking for a simple way to solve your problem, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest way is to compute the frequency manually e.g. via `count` or `group_by`+ `summarise` and use the aggregated df for plotting using `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`. Then you can reorder `Choice` via e.g. `forcats::fct_reorder` or `reorder` according to frequency.

Using some fake random data to mimic your dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(forcats)

set.seed(42)

all_data <- data.frame(
  Choice = sample(c("Painful", "Shook", "Humilation"), 30, replace = TRUE),
  Correct = sample(c("Stormy", "Truth"), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

# Aggregate your data outside of ggplot
all_data %>%
  filter(Correct == "Stormy") %>%
  count(Choice) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Choice, -n), n)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

And if you don't want to aggregate your data manually a second option would be to use `forcats::fct_infreq` in `geom_bar`:

```r
# Or using forcats::fct_infreq
all_data |>
  filter(Correct == "Stormy") |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = forcats::fct_infreq(Choice)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

The above answers would probably work really well, but I figured out the easiest way would probably be to:

```
install.packages("forcats")
library(forcats)
ggplot(filter(all_data, Correct == "Rage"), aes(fct_infreq(factor(Choice)))) + geom_bar()
```

Thank you so much all for all your help!